# Making a Button Stay Clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How do I make it so a button stay clicks after the user has exited the program?

Let's say I have this option(as a JButton) that sets the `JTextArea's` text to red. The user clicks the button, then exits the program. When the user opens the program back up, the text is red - meaning the button is still clicked.

If you don't get that example, let me show you another one:

I have a `JButton`, and a `JLabel`. When the button is clicked, it changes the background of the `JLabel` to blue. The user clicks the button, then exits the program. When the user opens the program back up, the button is already clicked, meaning the `JLabel`'s background color is blue.

Is there a way I can do that?

**Edit:** I would prefer if I could do it without loading external files.

**Edit 2:** I like the idea of using `Preference`. But, could you give me an examplre for me for one of the examples above? I'm *kind of* a beginner in Java, so I have a lot of questions. Like, does the code go in the `actionPerformed` of the button? And, how could I save different kinds of information(`JTextarea` foreground as red) with `Preferences`?

Comment: For your examples, I'd set the values when you create the JTextArea.  You can do it by doing `prefs.get("area's previous color", Color.WHITE);`  This will make it return WHITE if this is the first time the program has been run.  Otherwise, it will return the thing you put in there.  Then every time the color changes, put the `prefs.put` in the actionPerformed.

Comment: I need it to change colors ONLY when a button has been clicked.

Comment: I read a few years ago that preferences are stored in the registry if you have windows, and in a file if you have linux.

Comment: @user2228462 Then only `put` when it's clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You should use Preferences for this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)   That explanation is a little complex.  But basically it saves values that can be retrieved between runs.

[Here's a tutorial of how to use this with a JFileChooser.](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/simple-java-preferences-api-example)  Here's an example I wrote:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Sandbox.class);
        Integer counter = Integer.valueOf(prefs.get("counter", "0"));
        System.out.println(counter);
        counter++;
        prefs.put("counter", String.valueOf(counter));
    }
}
```

The first time you run this, it'll print "0".  The next time you run it, it'll print "1".

Comment: +1 Use `Integer.parseInt()` instead of using `Integer.valueOf()` :)

Comment: +1 For Preferences, -1 for `Integer.valueOf`.  Preferences has the ability to `get/putInt` (and all primitives) automatically, no need for parsing.  Check out [Preferences#getInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [Preferences#putInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#putInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 2):

> Edit 2: I like the idea of using Preference. But, could you give me an
>   examplre for me for one of the examples above? I'm kind of a beginner
>   in Java, so I have a lot of questions. Like, does the code go in the
>   actionPerformed of the button? And, how could I save different kinds
>   of information(JTextarea foreground as red) with Preferences?

Do it like this:

```
private static Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(className.class);
private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea textArea;

public void init()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    textArea = new JTextArea();

    // ...

    String storedValue = prefs.get("textAreaColor", null);
    if(storedValue != null)
    {
        Color color = new Color(Integer.parseInt(storedValue));
        textArea.setForeground(color);
    }

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
        {
            Color color = textArea.getForeground();
            int rgb = color.getRGB();
            prefs.put("textAreaColor", Integer.toString(rgb));
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for Preferences; to minimize conversions, also consider `getInt()` and `putInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

Save the settings to an external file. Then (try to) read that file when the program starts and apply the settings.

Comment: If you distribute your app as a jar, or an ear, this can be a pain.  There's many points of failure, too (eg: you gotta make sure the file path is OS agnostic, what happens if the file doesn't exist? What if the path doesn't exist?)  I think using a Preference is an easier way.

Comment: Agreed, `Preference` does indeed look better. I simply didn't know about it and this was the first that came to mind. ;)